# TextBox restricted to 20 chars English, 10 chars in Simplified Chinese

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I have WPF c# TextBox that has to be restricted to maximum of 20 chars in English, and 10 characters in Simplified Chinese, or other similar character set. I set the MaxLength property to 20 chars and it works fine when using the English keyboard, but if I chose the Chinese keyboard, it allows me to enter 20 Simplified Characters. Our database field is restricted to 20 bytes.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: have you tried to set the MaxLength property dynamically?

Comment: Chinese characters are 2 byte

Comment: @Jesse, I thought c# is all in unicode, so all characters are 2 bytes.

Comment: @gunr2171: *Unicode* does not automatically mean *UTF-16*. Also, what .NET/C# is, is probably not very relevant with respect to what the OP's database does.

Answer (score 4):

`MaxLength` counts the number of characters, not the number of bytes that is required to represent them. In fact, the byte representation of a string depends on the character encoding that is used. .NET natively uses UTF-16, in which all characters (English and Chinese) occupy 2 bytes. I assume that your database uses UTF-8, where English characters occupy 1 byte, and Chinese characters occupy 2 bytes.

You will need to enforce your limit dynamically. You can do so by implementing a `ValidationRule`, such as the one below. Read [Data validation in WPF](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) for an explanation of how to use this with your `TextBox`.

```
public class Byte20ValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value.ToString());
        if (byteCount <= 20)
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Too many bytes.");
    }
}
```

Comment: ".NET natively uses UTF-16, in which all characters (English and Chinese) occupy 2 bytes." This isn't *completely* accurate. All "normal" characters will occupy 2 bytes, but I believe there are still weird annotations on characters that can cause even UTF-16 to have to use more than 2 bytes for a single character.

Comment: @TimothyShields: You're right, but the OP's text most likely fits into the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters outside this plane would be represented using surrogate pairs.